# How to programmatically expand or collapse an Oracle JET ojCollapsible

Tags: oracle-jet

I am using Oracle Jet and I have this dialog where I show a "More Options" section using an `ojCollapsible` that is supposed to always show up collapsed when the dialog initially shows up.

When the dialog is closed and brought back, I need the `ojCollapsible` to show up closed again. How can I programmatically tell it to collapse?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it:

```
$(".selector").ojCollapsible( { "expanded": false} );
```

Use `true` if what you want is to have it expanded.

This turned out to be pretty simple and kind of obvious in retrospective, however, each time I spend some time without doing it I find myself in the same situation wondering how to do it and the cookbook doesn't include an example.

Comment: Use [API doc](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojCollapsible.html#expanded) or [DEV Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet410/jet/developer/toc.htm) to know more about any component in JET when you find Cookbook is not handy.

Comment: Thanks. The API doc is where I did find it, however, the Cookbook is what I always have "near me." If I don't find it there, I just google it. It's the easiest and what I and many other devs do. Posting here guarantees I will find it quickly next time.